# Issue while updating @OneToMany collection

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-onetomany

I am stuck at a point where i am trying to update a @OneToMany mapping.

Problem:
I have 2 entities: Criteria and Tasks. A criteria can contain multiple tasks.

```
class Criteria {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "criteria", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
    CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,
               org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL,
               org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE,
               org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.PERSIST })
     private Set<Task> tasks;
}

class Task {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CRITERIA_ID", nullable=false)
    private Criteria criteria;
}
```

I am trying to update an existing Criteria with new set of tasks. This requires removing all existing tasks and adding new tasks.
Here is how i am doing:

```
criteriaDao.persist(criteria);
Set<Task> existingTasks=criteria.getTasks();
if(existingTasks != null) {
    for (Task task : existingTasks) {
        task.setCriteria(null);
    }
    criteria.setTasks(tasks);
    //more code which sets criteria for each task - this works if i try to save new criteria with new tasks
}
```

Hibernate is throwing an exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (CCA_DEV_5.TASK__UN) violated
```

This exception is thrown because it didn't remove the existing tasks.

If i only delete all the tasks, it works perfectly and removed all the tasks for the given criteria with below code:

```
criteriaDao.persist(criteria);
Set<Task> existingTasks=criteria.getTasks();
if(existingTasks != null) {
    for (Task task : existingTasks) {
    task.setCriteria(null);
}
}
```

I tried all options of using merge after adding new tasks and more stuff but nothing seems to work for me. I am badly stuck here and definately missing something very basic in Hibernate.

Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 0):

In your `Task` class you should have no reference to `Criteria` at all. Just remove it along with its annotations.

Then, instead of setting the `Criteria` referenced by the `Task`, as this reference no longer exists, just use `criteria.setTasks(newTasks)` and save `criteria`.

---

Let me explain a bit. The relation between `Criteria` and `Task` is obvoiusly `Criteria 1 --- n Tasks` - 1 to n. Now, you can call `one-to-many` relation and you can call it `many-to-one`, depends on your point of view. Looking from `Criteria` oint of view, it's `one-to-many`, while looking from `Task` point of view - it's `many-to-one`. Generally, it's advisable and more intuitive to choose **one** of these point of views and **stick to it**. Choosing a point of view, defines the entity that "controls" the relation thorugh which any modification should be applied.

In your case, if you regard a `Criteria` as **containing** or **owning** a set of `Task`s - you'd treat the relation as `one-to-many`. After deciding that, no need for `Criteria` reference **in the java class** of `Task`. You control the relation solely with `Criteria` API (the table created for `Task` in the DB, however, does have a column that refers its containing `Criteria`).

Comment: Hmm...many-to-one in my opinion should work along with one-to-many, i haven't seen any issues with it. Also JPA supports inverse mapping. I got this fixed by adding following lines before setting the collection with new set collection- 
    for (Task task : existingTasks) {
        task.setCriteria(null);
    }
   => session.flush();
    criteria.setTasks(tasks);

This makes sure that the delete statements are executed before the inserts.

Comment: @RakeshSinha it's great that you solved the problem. However, I'd recommend you read [this short parent-child hibernate docs example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-parentchild-bidir) which explains how to use `inverse` in a `one-to-many` relation.

Comment: Thank you, i have seen this document in past and using the same. Do you think there is another way of achieving what i am doing.? Calling flush() explicitly works but that would cause entity manager to flush all the queries to Db. Is there a better way of updating a collection.?